# Slow boot after cloning my Ubuntu partition from HDD to SSD without swap

Tags: boot, grub2

So I had Ubuntu installed on my HDD along with a swap partition. I cloned only my Ubuntu partition (without swap) from HDD to a new SSD via live Gparted, installed grub on the new disk and (physically) removed the old drive from the system. The cloned installation is noticeably snappier than the one on HDD but it boots quite slow. With a bit of research I got to know that there might be a resume file which is still pointing to the old swap partition. However, I couldn't find it in /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d.

I don't intend to create a swap and just want the system to boot fast without looking for anything from previous disk. How do I fix?

Answer (score 1):

Okay so, removing the old partition entries from `/etc/fstab` made the system not look for the old partitions but still the kernel space was taking 35 sec to load.

Since I didn't have any `resume` file, I just ran `sudo update-initramfs -u` after which the system just stopped looking for anything from previous drive to resume from.

Now the boot time has been reduced from more than 2 mins to 13.8 seconds (2.5s kernel space + 11.3s user space) :D

Comment: Why did you not upgrade your RAM as long as you were updating the system?